# error: @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-context

would like to start TimerView() in onClick - TimerView is a text composable
but the above mentioned error appears - both are marked composables

```
Composable
fun LosB(BLY: String, YArray: ArrayList<String> /* = java.util.ArrayList<kotlin.String> */) {
    //  val Tit = mutableStateOf("sdfsdf")
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {


        OutlinedButton(
            onClick = { TimerView()},
            shape = CircleShape,
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color(0xFFADFF2F)),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFF1C536F),
                contentColor = Color.White
            )
        ) {


            Text(text = "OK", fontSize = 20.sp)

        }
    }
```

Any help? want to show a txt counter -

Comment: did you have chance to review the answers?

Answer (score 3):

You need just make a mutableState like this

```
var timeViewState by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}

if(timeViewState) {
   TimerView()
}

OutlinedButton(
   onClick = { timeViewState = true },
...
```

Home I help you

Answer (score 3):

I will come with a little explanation.
Composable functions are run in parallel, that means that Compose take care of internal thread pool to perform fast and optimized composition.

However, `onClick` takes place on UI thread, which is out of composition context and is not controlled by the thread pool, that is the reason why you cannot call composable function from `onClick`.

To perform such operation you indeed need to create a mutable state which will be controlled by the button.

```
var isTimerVisible by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}

if (isTimerVisible) {
    TimerView()
}

OutlinedButton(
        onClick = { isTimerVisible = !isTimerVisible },
        shape = CircleShape,
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color(0xFFADFF2F)),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = Color(0xFF1C536F),
            contentColor = Color.White
        )
) {
        Text(text = "OK", fontSize = 20.sp)
}
```

**UPD:** With the help from z.g.y I understood that I was not quite correct about it.

`@Compose` annotation works similar as a suspend keyword in Kotlin, it is changing the functions' type. Composable function type is just like `suspend` is not compatible with regular function type.

Compiler treats that type of function differently, it inserts `$composer` parameter to it and call its' `start` method with a generated integer key.

```
fun TimerView($composer: Composer) {
    $composer.start(123) 
}
```

This `composer` object is passed to composable from parent composable, but since `onClick` is not composable and happens outside of composition context, there is no valid composer in it. So you cannot call composable without the `composer`

*Compose, compose, compose...*

Good article to read about it is [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd)

Comment: Can you please remove the first part of the answer if that's not correct ?